# Restore Registered Agent which deleted accidentally

Tags: azure, azure-devops, cloud

I accidentally deleted all Registered Agent under "Default Pool" , please refer this attached screen shot [azure_agent_deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiVSE.png)

Now may applications(more than 50) builds are getting failed ,please help on this issue . Is there any way to restore the deleted Agents ? or any other way ? Because many teams application build is failing.
Please advice

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid there is currently no out-of-the-box option to restore the deleted private agent.

As workaround , you need to re-register the agents to add them back to the default agent pool. You can delete the `.agent`, `.credentials` and `.credentials_rsaparams` files in the root of the folder. After that run `./config.cmd` again and reconfigure as if it were a fresh install.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @hugh-lin-msft....one more question. We have many applications and those are running 10 different servers so i need to go each server and need to configure one by one , am i correct ?

Comment: Yes, that's right, there is no batch configuration method at present. If you call `config.cmd` of other servers one by one in a server, I think this is not very convenient.

Comment: Restored all Agents  as  per @hugh..Thanks